# Unsigned integer operation questions

Tags: c, math, binary

These are not assignments nor homework. 
I'm preparing my mid-test. I need someone to tell me which is the right answer, and explain to me why in detail.

```
[2 marks] Given an unsigned integer n, the operation (n & ~1) will produce
(a) the value n mod 4
(b) n with its least significant bit cleared (i.e. set to 0)
(c) the value 2n
(d) the value n/2
(e) the least significant bit of n

[1 mark] Given an unsigned integer n, the operation (n << 1) will produce
(a) n with its least significant bit cleared (i.e. set to 0)
(b) the value n mod 4
(c) the value n/2
(d) the least significant bit of n
(e) the value 2n
```

I don't know whether the follow 2 formula will help you to solve the problem:

```
if (c & 0x1 == 0x1)~c = c OR c-1 //odd colour value), 
if (c & 0x1 == 0x0)~c = c OR c+1 //even colour value.
```

Comment: Hmm.  Looks to me like the second question needs a "None of the above" answer.  (E.g., consider the case `n = 2147483648` on a system where unsigned integers are 32 bits.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson, the proposed number (= 0x80000000) when shifted left one bit will result in 1 in the carry bit and 0 in the rest of the number,  which is '2n'  therefore answer (e) is correct

Answer (score 1):

1. `(n & ~1)`

   - this is `n AND (not 1)`
   - `(not 1)` produce number 1 with all bits negated so `11111....11110b`
   - `AND` is bitwise multiplication so `0*?=0` , `1*1=1` ,`1*u=u`
   - two numbers are taken in binary form and each corresponding bits are multiplied
   - so after `AND` with this number the last bit is cleared and all the rest is left as was
   - so **(b)** is correct
2. `(n << 1)`

   - this is bit shift left by 1 bit
   - it is the same as multiplying by 2^1
   - `1b<<1 = 10b = 2`
   - `1b<<2 = 100b = 4`
   - `1b<<3 = 1000b = 8`
   - `5<<1=101b<<1=1010b=10`
   - it is analogy to multiplying by 10 in decimal numbers
   - so the answer **(e)** is correct unless overflow occurs
   - when `n<<1` has more bits then your variable can store then you cut of the MSB bit
   - on some compilers/platforms it goes to Carry but that could not always be the case
   - so true answer for 32 bit is `(n<<1)=(2*n) mod (2^32)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [ideone](http://ideone.com/DK7QaD) code and see what is the result

```cs
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        UInt32 n;

        n = 10245;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("n & ~1 - n = {0}, result = {1}", n, n & ~1));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("n << 1 - n = {0}, result = {1}", n, n << 1));
    }
}
```

Explanation of why relies on knowing how are the [bitwise operators defined](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html) and printing both input and output numbers in their [binary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_arithmetic) is the perspective that should explain things

Comment: that  code looks like the 'rust' language, It definitely is not C.

Comment: @user3629249 the runable "calculator" snippet is in `C#` but the bitwise operator semantics is same as the one in `Kernighan & Ritchie C`. I picked this language (although from other OP's questions it seems that `java` would be better) as here I remember how to say "print some formatted string to the typewriter" without need to search in the standard library help. For the quiz purpose the wrapping language should be irrelevant